# Mixture & Alligation problem

Tags: problem-solving, average

In what ratio must a person mix three kinds of wheat costing him 1.20,1.44 and 1.74 dollars per kg., so that the mixture formed is worth 1.41 dollars per kg?
a)11:77:7
b)12:7:7
c)ratio other than a and b
d)no solution

Is alligation valid here?

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions. To answer the question, one can check by substitution whether a) or b) work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to answer c without doing any computation at all.  As $1.41$ is between the upper and lower cost elements there is some mix that will produce it, so d is out.  If you had only two things you could mix you could find a unique mix that would produce that cost.  Given that you have three, there is a one dimensional set of solutions, so there will be some other than a and b.  If you trust the problem setter to have made a unique solution, neither a nor b should yield the correct cost.  You could check if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What would have been the solution if there were no options?

Comment: As I said, there are an infinite number of them.  You could find one using just the $1.20$ and $1.74$ wheat.  If fraction $x$ of the mix is $1.20$ you have $1.20x+1.74(1-x)=1.41$  For the mix using all three, if $x$ is the fraction of $1.20$ wheat and $y$ is the fraction of $1.44$, you have $1.20x+1.44y+1.74(1-x-y)=1.41$  One equation, two unknowns.

Comment: I think the word you are trying to use is allocation, but it doesn't really fit here.